# Can this words be used in this sentence?

Tags: word-request, word-difference

I am writing literature review and I've wrote that sentence:

> Arguing that there is **insufficient** suitable software that allows for collaborative browsing, the author’s team **conducts the research** to discover numerous issues that have to be fixed in their new system called PlayByPlay.

I an not sure if I use bolded words correctly.

Firstly I wanted to write not enough instead of **insufficient**, but it is illegal in this type of review.

Secondly I am not sure if it's correct to write **conduct** the research.

Thirdly, how can I substitute the word "fix" in that sentence? I think it's like "not enough" cannot be used in this type of work

Thanx for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rewrite.....
Explaining that there was insufficient software suitable for enabling collaborative browsing, the author’s team conducted research and discovered numerous issues that needed to be fixed in their new PlayByPlay system.

Comment: thanx a lot, but it should be in present simple as possible.

>Explaining that there is insufficient software suitable for enabling collaborative browsing, the author’s team conduct research and discoveres numerous issues that needed to be fixed in their new PlayByPlay system.

Is that all right?

Comment: I thought you were reporting on this. Anyway, just put it in the present simple. :) conductS, need to be fixed//discoverS.